# vue.js v class binding is overriding other bindings and not removing classes properly

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a punching bag "game" where I want to add an animation class one every click event. And when the health meter is down to zero, I am replacing the bag picture with an image of a burst bag.

This works ok as long I don't try to add the animation classes. When I try to add the animations, neither functionality is working.

The link is here: https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/mqXady

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="vue-app-one">
<!-- the bag images -->
<div id="bag" v-bind:class="[animationToggle ? activeClass : 'swingLeft', 
'noSwing']" v-bind:class="{ burst: ended }"></div>

<!-- health meter -->
<div id="bag-health">
  <div v-bind:class="[danger ? activeClass : 'dangerous', 'safe']" v-
bind:style="{ width: health + '%'}"></div>
</div>


 <!-- the game buttons -->

 <div id="controls">
    <button v-on:click="punch" v-show="!ended">Punch it!</button>
      <button v-on:click="restart">Restart game</button>
 </div>

 </div>
```

The problematic part is this:

```
<div id="bag" v-bind:class="[animationToggle ? activeClass : 'swingLeft', 
'noSwing']" v-bind:class="{ burst: ended }"></div>
```

// Above I try to bind the noSwing CSS class as default and change it to swingLeft if the animationToggle property changes. However, this adds both classes when I check dev tools, and no animation is happening.Can I have 2 class bindings on 1 element like that?

// Further, I bind the ended property to the burst CSS class, this only works if I remove the animationToggle binding and all the relevant CSS.

The instance looks like this:

```
var one = new Vue({
el: '#vue-app-one',
data: {
health: 100, //init health bar, this works
ended: false, // init ended state, works partially
punched: false, //init punched, don't need for now
danger: false, // this works
animationToggle: false, // there is a problem with this
activeClass: "" // have to init or I get the errors in the console
 },
methods: {

  punch: function(){
      this.health -=10; //works
      this.animationToggle= true; // is set on click
      if(this.health <= 0){
        this.ended = true; // works partially, the background img change is not working ,though
      }
      if(this.health <= 20){
        this.danger = true; // works
      }
      else{
        this.danger = false;
      }
      setTimeout(function () {
          this.animationToggle = false // I am not sure this ever works, give no error, but I am still not sure
          }.bind(this),500);

  },
  restart: function(){
    this.health =100;
    this.ended = false; // works partially, no img change when health is 0, though
  }
}

});
```

The relevant CSS:

```
#bag.noSwing {
width: 300px;
height: 500px;
margin: -80px auto;
background: url("https://3.imimg.com/data3/VM/TI/MY-18093/classical-heavy-
bag-250x250.png") center no-repeat;
background-size: 70%;
-webkit-animation-name: swingRight;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.11,.91,.91,.39);
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-transform-origin: center;
      transform-origin: center;
 }

#bag.swingLeft {
width: 300px;
height: 500px;
margin: -80px auto;
background: url("https://3.imimg.com/data3/VM/TI/MY-18093/classical-heavy-
bag-250x250.png") center no-repeat;
background-size: 70%;
-webkit-animation-name: swingLeft;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-transform-origin: right;
      transform-origin: right;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.91,.11,.31,.69);

 }


@keyframes swingLeft {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate (0deg); transform: rotate (0deg); }
20% { -webkit-transform: rotate (-20deg); transform: rotate (-20deg); }
50% { -webkit-transform: rotate (20deg); transform: rotate (20deg); }
70% { -webkit-transform: rotate (-10deg); transform: rotate (-10deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate (0deg); transform: rotate (0deg); }
}

@keyframes swingRight {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate (0deg); transform: rotate (0deg); }
 20% { -webkit-transform: rotate (20deg); transform: rotate (20deg); }
50% { -webkit-transform: rotate (-20deg); transform: rotate (-20deg); }
70% { -webkit-transform: rotate (10deg); transform: rotate (10deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate (0deg); transform: rotate (0deg); }
}

 #bag.burst {

 background: url("http://i.imgur.com/oRUzTNx.jpg") center no-repeat;
 background-size: 70%;

 }

 #bag-health {
 width: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #004;
 margin: -80px auto 20px auto;
 }

#bag-health div.safe {
height: 20px;
background: #44c466;
}
```

#bag-health div.dangerous {

background: #00ffff;
   }

So why are the animations not applied when the "punch it" button is clicked, why does it add both the noSwing and swingLeft class? And it overrides the functionality which changes the background image to a burst bad when the health meter reaches a value of zero.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `:class` props on one div? Never done this so not sure if its causing problems.

Comment: @webnoob, it is my second day with vue.js, I could not find anything in the docs, I am not sure it is allowed nor am I sure it's the right syntax, but it does not give me any error messages, and applies the classes, the problem is, it does not remove one of them. Maybe it's the setTimeout in the instance method. One class binding definitely works as it should, The array syntax is straight from the docs, that's fine as well, I know there is an object syntax to use v bind.

Comment: You realise the `noSwing` class will *always* be applied as you've added it to the end of the array? Should that be conditional?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you **can't** have 2 class bindings on the same element, nor should you need them.

You have quite a lot of logic regarding adding/removing classes, so i would suggest extracting it to a computed:

```
computed: {
  className () {
      let classes= [];
          if (this.animationToggle){
             classes.push(this.activeClass)
          }
          else{
             classes.push('swingLeft')
          }
      return classes;

      }
  }
}


<div id="bag" :class="className"></div>
```

Comment: This works the same like my code did, but it overrides the "{ burst: ended }" binding, thanks for clarifying only one class binding is possible. Is there a  solution to the second binding, as it is never applied.? The removal of the class in the method is causing issues as well, if I remove it, nothing works, if I leave it there, the animation starts not as it should. If you can check, the code on the pen right now is what I describe above.
Would perhaps a v-on:click="!animationToggle" (on the punch it button"do the trick?

Comment: This is just an example, you can add to this array any class you want! just push 'burst' to the array and it will be added

Comment: Hm, if I apply both in the array, it immediately adds the burst class. To add the burst class only at the end, I will need another if clause, right?
Another thing is why is every click re-rendering the whole image?

Comment: You need to add/remove the burst class according according to the logic you need, so obviously it will require if/else. I have no idea why the entire image renders.